# Edits that happen at the same time are not handled well

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

I edited [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/45147/is-it-wrong-to-make-things-too-easy) and I guess I tried to edit at the same time as someone else so my edits and theirs got combined in a strange way.

I removed the first line and the thanks, the person who edited before/at the same time removed the line "Am I just being strange?". Since I did not remove that line, in the "Review Suggested Edit" page, it was interpreted as me *adding* "Am I just being strange?" which I did not do.

Potential changes should probably be saved as the diff instead of as a whole so that issues like this can be avoided.

This is also another use case for allowing communication between reviewers and the people who've made the suggested edits so that I can easily say "not calling OP strange!"

Answer (score 1):

Someone with enough reputation to make post edits has made an edit to the question, just before you had posted a suggested edit. That edit went in.

A couple of hours later, your edit got approved. It overwrote the prior edit.

It is an edge case.

Comment: It may be an edge case, but it [happens often enough](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3149/different-users-edits-are-amalgamated) for something to be done about it. Different users should not have their edits amalgamated.